# sed to search and replace in case of multiple spaces

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a file with following content and now I need to replace `no` with `yes` by searching '`enable-cache passwd`' I cannot search simply with '`passwd`' as the file may have some other entries.

```
#       enable-cache            <service> <yes|no>
        enable-cache            passwd          no
        enable-cache            group           no
        enable-cache            hosts           yes
        enable-cache            services        yes
        enable-cache            netgroup        no
```

Comment: An easy enough task. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am unable to search multiple spaces. Tried the following.

`sed -n -e '/ *enable-cache *passwd/ p' /etc/nscd.conf
 sed -n -e '/\{1,\}enable-cache\{1,\}passwd/ p' /etc/nscd.conf ` 

But still not working, Just for testing I am using `p` command instead I want to use `substitute` command actually.

Comment: How about `sed 's/\(^\s*enable-cache\s\+passwd\s\+\)no/\1yes/g'`?

Comment: Great, This works for me. Thank You very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it.  If you decide that portability is not an issue, you can use shorter notations than if portability is an issue.

#### Portable

```
sed -e '/^[[:space:]]*enable-cache[[:space:]]\{1,\}passwd[[:space:]]\{1,\}no[[:space:]]*$/ {
            s/no[[:space:]]*$/yes/
        }'
```

The ghastly first line looks for zero or more space-like characters (blanks, tabs) at the start of the line, followed by `enable-cache`, one or more space-like characters, the word `passwd`, one or more space-like characters, the word `no`, and zero or more space-like characters and the end of line.  This matches the lines that are interesting.  The second line contains a simpler pattern that replaces the `no` and any trailing space with just `yes` (deleting the trailing space if there was any — you didn't want it anyway).  This can be simpler because the elaborate expression has ensured that only the interesting lines are found.  The braces simply group things; it could all be done on one line without the braces if you don't mind long lines.

#### GNU `sed`

GNU [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) and the `-r` option provides some shorthands, notably `\s` to mean `[[:space:]]` and `+` to mean `\{1,\}`, which allows that to be compressed to:

```
sed -r -e '/^\s*enable-cache\s+passwd\s+no\s*$/ s/no\s*$/yes/'
```